# ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server. Error Code: [-1] Diagnostic Message: null

Tags: laravel, openldap

I am trying to connect ldap test server with laravel authentication.

ldap configuration in .env,

```
 LDAP_LOGGING=true
 LDAP_CONNECTION=default
 LDAP_HOST=ldap.forumsys.com
 LDAP_USERNAME='cn=user,dc=local,dc=com' 
 LDAP_PASSWORD=secret
 LDAP_PORT=389 
 LDAP_BASE_DN="dc=local,dc=com" 
 LDAP_TIMEOUT=5
 LDAP_SSL=false 
 LDAP_TLS=false
```

But I got this error.
ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server. Error Code: [-1] Diagnostic Message: null

When I test ping in terminal(`ping ldap.forumsys.com`), it return like this.

```
ping ldap.forumsys.com
PING ldap.forumsys.com (52.87.186.93): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
```

Is that ldap.forumsys.com down? Can somebody explain this? It's working before and I didn't make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're password has to be "*password*"